# Java sleep thread in Junit test case

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, synchronization

I am trying to create a synchronized version of data and using junit to test my method. The code below is what I came so far. It works quite well if I put on the main method (the counter is increased one by one by each thread) but the test process will stop immediately. Is this the problem by using `Thread.sleep()` on a test case?

```java
    public void testGeneral() {
        class SynchronizedData {
            public AtomicBoolean lock = new AtomicBoolean(false);
            public int counter = 0;

            public void update() {
                if(lock.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    lock.set(false);
                }
            }
        }

        SynchronizedData data = new SynchronizedData();

        class Handler implements Runnable {
            String name;

            public Handler(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(;;) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(100));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    System.out.println(this.name);
                    data.update();
                }
            }
        }

        new Thread(new Handler("One")).start();
        new Thread(new Handler("Two")).start();
    }
```

Comment: Please show (at least) the `@Test` case that doesn't work. You aren't likely to get much help solving your problem if you don't show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Sorry if I was vague in my question, but the code above is the one that doesn't work in TestCase context, but works properly if I put it in my Main() method.

Comment: You showed some code, and you said, "it works quite well," and maybe I am assuming too much, but it _seems_ as if the "it" that "works quite well" is the code in your example. You also said that you are having trouble writing a JUnit test for your code. So, it seems as if the problem is in your JUnit code, but where is the JUnit code that doesn't work? How about showing something that calls `JUnitCore.runClasses(MyTests.class);`? And, how about showing us a `class MyTests {...}` with an `@Test` method that fails to prove that your unit under test "works quite well"?